# While pulling the albums of an artist in Spotify, how do I increase the default limit of 20?

Tags: spotify

While pulling the albums of an artist in Spotify using Spotify API, how do I increase the default limit of 20? I want all the songs of the artist or at least the top 1000 songs to be displayed.

Answer (score 1):

When using [Get Artist's Albums](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/get-an-artists-albums) you can get up to 50 items at a time, but even so the results are returned as a paging object so you can keep requesting the **Albums of an Artist** and increment the offset by 50 to get the next set of records until you get them all, for example for 1,000 albums for an artists that's only 20 requests.